# Implode() not Working in While Loop

Tags: php, arrays

Confused as to why I am getting this message

> Warning: implode(): Invalid arguments passed

Here is my script

```
$out = "";
while($row = $results->fetch_array()) {

    // do stuff here to create an indexed array

    $arraycount = count($array);
    for ($i=0; $i < $arraycount; $i++) {
        foreach($array as $arr) {
            $out .= implode(";", $arr) . "<br>";
        }
    }
}
```

I know `$array` is a proper indexed array.. if I do this before or after my for/foreach loop:

```
echo '<pre>';
print_r($array);
echo '</pre>';
```

The output is all my arrays

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array 1 Node 1
    [1] => Array 1 Node 2
    [2] => Array 1 Node 3
    [3] => Array 1 Node 4
    [4] => Array 1 Node 5
)

Array
(
    [0] => Array 2 Node 1
    [1] => Array 2 Node 2
    [2] => Array 2 Node 3
    [3] => Array 2 Node 4
    [4] => Array 2 Node 5
)

Array
(
    [0] => Array 3 Node 1
    [1] => Array 3 Node 2
    [2] => Array 3 Node 3
    [3] => Array 3 Node 4
    [4] => Array 3 Node 5
)

etc. etc. etc.
```

The output I'm looking to get out of all of this, if you can't tell by the loop, is a csv-like file with a `;` delimiter.

This loop works fine outside of the loop, but then I'm having the issue of it not retrieving all the results from each loop-- so doing it within the loop as I am attempting I believe is ideal.

Anyone know what I'm doing wrong/why this isn't working in the while loop?

Comment: `implode(";", $arr)` -- Is `$arr` an array? [`implode()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php) expects the second argument to be an array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like `$array` is an array of strings. In that case, you shouldn't need the inner `for` or `foreach` loops. If each instance of `$array` is one of these:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array 1 Node 1
    [1] => Array 1 Node 2
    [2] => Array 1 Node 3
    [3] => Array 1 Node 4
    [4] => Array 1 Node 5
)
```

Then you should be able to implode that directly.

```
$out = "";
while($row = $results->fetch_array()) {

    // do stuff here to create an indexed array

    $out .= implode(";", $array) . "<br>";
}
```

---

By the way, the `// do stuff here to create an indexed array` *may* not be necessary. I'm not sure exactly what it does, but you can specify in your fetch method that it should fetch a numerically indexed array.

```
while($row = $results->fetch_array(MYSQLI_NUM)) { ...
```

(Or just use the `fetch_row` method instead.)

Comment: You are correct :)  I did the something similar after reading @axiac's comment.  Just removed the `foreach` portion and imploding my `$array`.  You made it simpler though as I was still leaving in my `for` loop with the array count-- which I suppose is not needed.  Anyways, thank you!!

Comment: @user8046043 If this is being output to a file, you may be able to use `fputcsv` instead of building the `$out` string and then outputting that to your file. It does accept different delimiters, so you could use semicolon instead of comma.

Comment: Good idea. My plan was to just copy the output and paste it in a text file and change it to a .csv.  But the output is so large its freezing my browser so I'm having difficulties even copying it.  Thanks for the tip

Comment: Oh yeah. In that case, creating the file directly should be a much better option. You're welcome. :)